# High CPU utilisation Spring boot application while no user is using the app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm running a spring boot application on tomcat server, everything was fine (service was up for more than 700 h) but in one moment the CPU usage was extremely height and he stays like that until I restarted the tomcat

[image: kibana]

I'have  Actuator Metrics configured to log every 10 mins, in the screen below you can see the difference of CPU usage. There are no application log between the first and the second Metrics log, what's mean that the application wasn't used by end users at this time.

Actuator Metrics :

[image: Meter Registry]

Any suggestion, thanks in advance.

Comment: The after image shows 5 busy threads in Tomcat handling HTTP requests on port 8080 so, despite the lack of logging, it would appear that something is making requests to the application.

Comment: Take a thread dump while the CPU usage is high and you'll see exactly what the process is doing.

Comment: Thanks ChristopherSchultz, AndyWilkinson